# Javascript context menu which changes a variable upon click

Tags: javascript, three.js

in my three.js application I am right clicking floors (BoxGeometry) which makes a context menu appear so I can select from a range of different textures. While this is working correctly for one floor, I want to make it work for several.

Here's texture & material 1:

```
const loaderT = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const texture1 = loaderT.load( './textures/32995.jpg' );  
 const box = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 25, .3, 25);
 
    const material1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture1 } ); 
    
    floor1 = new THREE.Mesh( box, material1 );
    floor1.position.set(-12.5,0,-12.5);
    

//and repeat for the other textures
```

My function to change floors looks like:

```
function changeFloor(event)
let targetID = parseInt(event.target.id,10);
var texture;
switch(targetID){
case 35:
      texture = texture1;
      break;
case 36:
      texture = texture2;
      break;
case 37:
      texture = texture3;
      break;
case 38:
      texture = texture4;
      break;       
}
ultimateMat.map = texture;

menu.style.display = "none";
}
```

Where the IDs are the different selection choices on the context menu. I am trying to  get the ultimateMat variable to change depending on what floor I right click.

Currently I have this on my mouse down function:

```
function onMouseDown(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var rightclick;
    if (!event) var event = window.event;
    if (event.which) rightclick = (event.which == 3);
    else if (event.button) rightclick = (event.button == 2);
  if (!rightclick) return;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
 

  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([floor1, floor2, floor3, floor4]);

  if (intersects.length) {
    intersect = intersects[0].object;
    
    menu.style.left = (event.clientX - rect.left) + "px";
    menu.style.top = (event.clientY - rect.top) + "px";
    
    document.getElementById("menuTitle").innerHTML = intersect.name;
    menu.style.display = "";
  }
  else{
    intersect = undefined;
  }
  
}
```

how do I make the ultimateMat variable change to material1 when I right-click floor1, and change to material2 when I then click floor2 and so on?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it ;)

I used another switch statement yo do the trick:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([floor1, floor2, floor3, floor4]);

  if (intersects.length) {
    intersect = intersects[0].object;
    switch(intersect){
    case floor1:
    ultimateMat = material1;
    break;
    case floor2:
    ultimateMat = material2;
    break;
    case floor3:
    ultimateMat = material3;
    break;
    case floor4:
    ultimateMat = material4;
    break;

    }
```